# Xcode 6.1.1 writes too much data to disk

Tags: macos, xcode, ssd

Recently I noticed that Xcode writes too much data to the disc. Within just 40 hours it wrote more than 13GB to the disk.

[image]

I restarted Xcode to see what actions cause this insane data transfer. I noticed that typing just one character makes Xcode write 40-50 MB of data onto the disk. As I have an SSD this makes me very "uncomfortable" using Xcode.

**How can I find out where the data is written and why it is written?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you have a normal Xcode installation and you can confirm this with Instruments or `fs_usage`

You'll want to let it finish downloading any documentation and close project windows that you don't work on to focus on the background file IO.

`sudo fs_usage -w Xcode  | grep -v Terminal`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Using fs_usage I found a file(s) which gets created every time I type a character and every time the window focus is taken away from Xcode. In these cases a *.pch file which gets deleted and a new one gets written to the disk with a new name. The size of the file is 18MB which correlates with with the 40MB disk write assuming I type a character and replace the focus: 2x18MB ~ 40MB. The path of the file is:

`-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff    18M Feb 11 11:28 /private/var/folders/rl/86xn039j3x3dhngbcp7qsyt40000gn/T/preamble-8d0fb6.pch`

Comment: I tried disabling header pre-compilation but it didn't help:
[Xcode settings screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/QQkX68E.png?1)

Comment: This only happens if I edit header (*.h, *.hpp) files but not when editing *.cpp files.

Comment: Yes - I was also surprised at the volume of file activity, but I'm not really seeing any indication that the SSD can't handle it. For Macs I want to keep for 3 years, I get Applecare and the rest I'm not keeping for 18 months due to a) how fast CPU and wireless are getting better b) the resale value of 2 year old Macs makes the upgrade cost so little compared to the value I get. I'm not able to wear out SSD and they are proving to be so much better than HDD it's not even funny what we put up with in the past for storage failures.